# R:Custom color palette in map with spplot

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, spatial

I am struggling with introducing a custom color palette on several polygons using `spplot` from the `sp` package. 
I am plotting several fields and want to show my rating , which can have the values 0,1,2,4 or 5. I need to use custom colors for that. What I tried is:

```
spplot(Map,zcol="Rating", 
       col.regions=c("0"="#00cc00","1"="#ffff66","2"="#e5c100",
                     "3"="orange","4"="#ff5e5e","5"="red"), 
       colorkey=TRUE)
```

However, it is producing a repetition of colors like in the map below. How can I solve this? I know how I can to it with ggplot, but for several reasons I need to know how to do it with spplot.
Thank a lot for your help.

**Edit:** Here an example with a map that does work the way I need it:

```
con <- url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/DEU_adm3.RData")
print(load(con))
close(con)
t1<-gadm[grep("Sachsen|Hessen|Bayern",gadm$NAME_1),]
col=c("red","yellow")
spplot(t1,zcol="TYPE_3",col.regions=col)
```

I noticed the following: When I subset the original "Large SpatialPolygonsDataframe" with my data, the resulting map is a "Formal Class SpatialPolygonsDataframe". This does not happen in the example I just posted above. Can anyone tell me what causes this behaviour? Unfortunately I cannot upload the original (sensitive) data.

[image: Map produced by spplot with repetitive color code (not desired)]

Comment: Does it work the way you expect if you change your code to `col.regions=c("#00cc00", "#ffff66", "#e5c100", "orange", "#ff5e5e", "red")`

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that others can reproduce your problem and try to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when your `zcol` is `numeric`. Convert it to `factor` and your plot should appear as expected.

You can see this behaviour if you convert `t1$TYPE_3` to numeric:

```
t1$TYPE_3.num <- as.numeric(t1$TYPE_3)
spplot(t1, 'TYPE_3.num', col.regions=c('red', 'yellow'))
```

[image: t1]

So assuming there are 6 possible factor levels, with labels 0 through 5, try:

```
Map$Rating.fac <- factor(M$Rating, levels=0:5)
```

and then use `zcol='Rating.fac'` and pass a vector of 6 colours to `col.regions`.